# Comma in "Experiencing P as well as Q, changed D"

Tags: commas

> Experiencing both sides of the X versus Y argument as someone who used
>   both as well as both sides of the A versus B argument as a
>   professional, altered my view of C.

Is the last comma in this sentence correct? (", altered")

I know that punctuation is dictated by the sound of the sentence, and when I talk the sentence out loud it seems that there should be a comma. But for the shortened version it sounds as if there should not be a comma.

> "Experiencing P as well as Q changed D"

Comment: For it to work you'll probably want another comma in that sentence: "Experiencing both sides of the X-versus-Y argument as someone who used both, as well as both sides of the A-versus-B argument as a professional, altered my view of C." It still doesn't feel 100% graceful, though. I'd probably look for a different way to express those ideas.

Comment: I think em dashes or parenthesis would make more sense. But a complete rewrite would make most sense.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that your suggested summary,

> Experiencing P as well as Q changed D

does not require a comma. However, you have two parenthetical statements in your sentence that have been omitted in your summary. The second of these statements comes right before your suggested comma, which may be why it feels natural to put a comma there. Parenthetical statements typically require comma, dashes or parentheses.

A more complete rephrasing is the following

> Experiencing P as a Q as well as R as an S changed T.

The fact that your summary removed those asides makes it clear that they are not essential components of the sentence and should be offset:

> Experiencing P, as a Q, as well as R, as an S, changed T.

Expanding back to the full sentence:

> Experiencing both sides of the X versus Y argument, as someone who
>   used both, as well as both sides of the A versus B argument, as a
>   professional, altered my view of C.

I agree with Thomas that the sentence could use some work. If you do stick with the current wording, I recommend adding parentheses rather than just commas to make it as clear as possible.

> Experiencing both sides of the X versus Y argument (as someone who
>   used both) as well as both sides of the A versus B argument (as a
>   professional) altered my view of C.

Comment: Clear analysis. @JoeBlack Yet no matter how correctly it's commaed or parenthesizified, the sentence is stylistically tormenting. Is there a reason it can't be something more like: My view of C was changed because I have argued both sides of the XY debate, and because (as a professional) I have argued both sides of the AB debate.

Comment: +1 analysis. I agree that sentence is not coming off easy to read. In the context of the piece it makes sense that the reasons/experiences come first in the sentence. I have cut down/modified the original to "The experience with both sides of X versus Y as Z and A versus B as C altered my view on Q". Still too long. Total sentence runs 46 words!

Answer (score 0):

It is correct because it helps reduce the number of incorrect guesses a reader or listener may need to make in interpreting the sentence with its long, unwieldy subject.

The short example is better with the comma, too, because it helps readers resolve what may be experienced as an ambiguity. A typical reader will be forced to pause and decide what things are connected by *as well as.* Without the comma, it is more likely that the thought process will go something like:

*(Something) AND (Q [subject/agent]) changed D [predicate].*

The typical reader can then go back and figure out that it must be:

*Experiencing P and (also experiencing Q) + predicate*

I think the comma will reduce the chance that a reader will need to run down such a mental rabbit trail, or that the comma will help resolve such a decision faster.

Comment: Why would the short example, "experiencing P as well as Q changed D," need a comma?

Comment: I was afraid someone would ask that. Not "needs", but benefits from. The first thing I see in that text is an opportunity to parse incorrectly: *[something] AND ALSO [Q changed D].* With *Q* misinterpreted as a subject/agent and *changed D* as a corresponding predicate. I invoke  the high rule of using punctuation when it can reasonably be expected to clarify, whether or not there is some corresponding use on a list of comma rules.

Comment: Let me clarify: I think the single comma before "changed" is ungrammatical. Let's look at the structure: the subject (experiencing P and Q) changed the object (D). You would not say "X, changed Y".  "Experiencing P, as well as Q, changed D" might work for the short case, which matches your clarification where you placed the second phrase in parenthesis.

Comment: AlannaRose, that's a good point. I think it goes back to the issue of whether one considers comma like devices to be separate from the grammar issue (they're probably not).